# PHP: Generating PNG thumbnail images from PNG source crashes function based on PNG size

Tags: php, image, png, thumbnails

I've written this small function to generate thumbnail images of a larger jpg/jpeg/png source, and it works perfectly on jpg/jpeg images, but depending on the size of the png image, will crash the function at an indeterminate point. Small 300x200 images work, yet something like 2880x1800 will not.

Here's my (annotated) function:

```
function make_thumb($filename, $destination, $desired_width) {
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Read source image
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
    } else if ($extension == 'png') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); // I think the crash occurs here. 
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }

    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    $img_ratio = floor($height / $width);

    // Find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    // Create a new "virtual" image
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    // Copy source image at a resized size
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    // Create the physical thumbnail image to its destination 
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg') {
        $source_image = imagejpeg($virtual_image, $destination); 
    } else if ($extension == 'png') {
        $source_image = imagepng($virtual_image, $destination, 1);
    } else {
        return 'another error';
    }
}
```

The only documentation I found that mentioned similar issues to me was [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#67854). Is this my problem? Any solutions? Why does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably running out of memory. 2880 x 1800 in true color will need about 20 Megabyte.

Check your php.ini for `memory_limit`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. That or PHP is really bad at handling large PNG images. This comment from the PHP documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php#104913) for `imagepng()` says:

> My script was unable to complete: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XX+n bytes).
>
> I found out that PHP handles images in uncompressed format: my input image was 8768x4282@32 bit => ~150 MB per single in-memory copy.
>
> As a solution, you can either check the dimensions and reject anything too big or, as I did, use ini_set('memory_limit','1024M'); on the page start (if your server has enough on board memory).

So, remember to increase your available memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');`!!!